# polymer / page.js change route in javascript without causing page refresh

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I use Polymer starter kit to build my app. I removed the hashbang in the urls.

I am trying to build a login screen and after successful login, I want to change the page to default route. To do this, I have a listener in app.js for successful log in. On successful log in, I change the route which causes page refresh. I tried multiple options:

1. location = 'entireUrl'
2. location.pathname = '/route'
3. location = 'route'

All the options causes page refresh. Is there any way to code this without causing page refresh. Shouldn't page.js catch this and do the routing without page refresh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those looking for an answer, I fixed it by calling page.redirect('/route').

note: page.redirect will replace the browser history. If you want to retain browser history you can use page.show('/route')

Comment: Where does "page" come from...?